# Has New Horizon's data updated Charon's orbital elements?

Tags: pluto, charon

For years I've been fascinated with the mutually tide-locked bodies Pluto and Charon. In July 2012, The Astronomical Journal published an article [The Orbit of Charon Is Circular](http://iopscience.iop.org/1538-3881/144/1/15/pdf/1538-3881_144_1_15.pdf) by Buie, Tholen and Grundy. The authors thought that the eccentricity of Charon's orbit is very close to zero.

It seems to me their opinion is somewhat speculative given the low quality of images from Hubble. Has New Horizons data verified Charon's circular orbit? Is there an online source giving more precise orbital elements from New Horizons data?

I'm also interested in the obliquity of Pluto and Charon.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but ftp://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/eph/satellites/nio/LINUX_PC/plu049.txt dated 12-Jul-2015 is the latest ephemeris file for Pluto and its satellites. However, the comments read "Ephemeris fit to all data including all New Horizons pre-encounter optical navigation imaging.", suggesting it hasn't yet been updated with actual encounter data. Keep an eye on ftp://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/eph/satellites/nio/LINUX_PC/ for new releases.

Comment: Finally. ftp://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/eph/satellites/nio/LINUX_PC/plu055l.txt (dated 5 Nov 2015). Quoting "Ephemeris for Pluto's satellites updated to include New Horizons data. This ephemeris is the basis of the work reported at the 2015 DPS meeting."

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the JPL Horizons system. You can investigate how Charon's orbital elements change with time. The short answer is, not surprisingly, not by much. The values for the eccentricity I see hover around 0.00015 and those for the orbital inclination relative to Pluto's equatorial plane are about 0.09 degrees.

http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi